# Crash ExoPlayer.Builder in android version 5 and 6 (android api 21 and 23)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash, exoplayer

When I upgrade exoplayer to version 2.16.0, it crashes when I run the line below the code:

`exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()`

I tested on higher Androids version like 10 and 11 (android api 29 and 30) and there is no problem, but in Android version 5 and 6 it crashes (android api 21 and 23)
Previously, in version 2.11.8, which I used, it ran without any problems in all versions of Android, but since I updated it to version 2.16.0, I have seen this problem in Android version 5 and 6.

What should I do to solve this problem?

My error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer$Builder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer$Builder.<init>(ExoPlayer.java:440)
     at com.myapp.Activity.VideoActivity_Online.onCreate(VideoActivity_Online.kt:58)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0 in my project and face same issue with Exoplayer. Probably moshi codegen breaks desugaring mechanics (Exoplayer code contains java 8 lambdas).
If you use moshi too, try downgrade or upgrade moshi version. Also check other code generation tools used by your project.

Upd:
I found that in one of project modules i use `implementation com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0` instead `kapt com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0`. After replacing from `implementation` to `kapt` all works as expected.

Comment: Hi! How  can I check other code generation tools in my project? I am having the same problem but I'm not using Moshi....

Comment: You can create a simple test project. Then add libraries and tools one by one from your main project. You should check for problems with exoplayer after every step. When problematic tools will be found, you may downgrade or upgrade them.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was caused by this dependency: 
`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava` (don't ask me why, it doesn't make any sense to be honest), which I used to await a `ListenableFuture` within a `CoroutineScope`.

I solved by removing the dependency.

**EDIT**:
The problem is there's a library that uses Java 8 language features. You need to enable [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).